# Let variable issue

Tags: javascript

I'm using **let variable** because I want to access to **Mistake's variable** just in do-while loop.

My main goal it's repeat this loop when Mistake is **true**.

However when Mistake is **true** and leaves from the statement, it shows **Mistake is not defined** and I don't understand why, because my **let variable** exists in this loop.

**My code**:

```
function CheckError()
{
   do
   {
     let Mistake = false;
        
     let Number = prompt("Choose a number between 1 - 4");
     Number = parseInt(Number);

     if(Number < 1 || Number > 4)
     {
        Mistake = true;
      }
   }while(Mistake == true);
}

CheckError();
```

Comment: It exists in the loop _body_, but the condition isn't part of the body. You have to put it outside of the loop or use an infinite loop with break/continue as needed. (If it was a `while` loop and not `do...while` then you could also have used `for` which creates an intermediate scope between the outer scope and the inner body scope.)

Comment: The while condition is outside of the loop scope, so this statement is obviously not true: `I want to access to Mistake's variable just in do-while loop.`

Comment: ps. Just so you can learn about block scopes and a general refresher on variables in JS, visit this: https://ui.dev/var-let-const/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The issue is that const and let are only available within the scope they are defined in, a simple way of pictureing it is, whenever you have this brackets {}, and inside there is a const or let, they are not available outside of the brackets.

So you have to define it one level higher, like so:

```js
function CheckError()
{
  let Mistake;
  do
  {
    Mistake = false;
    
    let Number = prompt("Choose a number between 1 - 4");
    Number = parseInt(Number);

    if(Number < 1 || Number > 4)
    {
      Mistake = true;
    }
  } while(Mistake == true);
}

CheckError();
```

PS. please make sure to set the Mistake to false still within the loop, otherwise you are stuck in a loop once you make a mistake.

Comment: I see!, so I need to define my let variable outside from do while loop as function variable, because while statement is outside of brackets.   Am I right?

Comment: Besides, I think it's not necessary define false value in the first Mistake's variable, because inside my loop it'll change to false and so on.

Comment: Yes, both of your statements are correct! I am glad you got the idea!

Answer (score 1):

you actually have to define the variable before the loop because the loop condition can't use the variable defined in its own block.

like this:

```
function CheckError()
{
  let Mistake = false;
  do
  {
    Mistake = false;
    let Number = prompt("Choose a number between 1 - 4");
    Number = parseInt(Number);

    if(Number < 1 || Number > 4)
    {
      Mistake = true;
    }
  } while(Mistake == true);
}

CheckError();
```

Answer (score -1):

```
function checkError() {
  let number = parseInt(prompt("Choose a number between 1 - 4"))
  if (number > 4 || number < 1){
        checkError();
    }
}

checkError();
```

Shorter function with same functionality

Comment: This is prone to stack overflows (however unlikely), and currently has no useful way to use `number` afterwards.

Comment: Just like the question itself?